# Check decimal places that are not 0

Tags: mysql, rounding, number-formatting

Currently I have this field in my database that is a (16, 10) double. I need to change this to a ( 16, 4 ) double. the only problem is that I have a lot of records and I need to check if some any of those records are using more than 4 decimal places. Something like 1500.3333333. The problem is that by changing just changing the field to (16,4) I get zeros to the right, like 14,5500.

Is there any way, using Mysql that I can check if the double is using more than 4 decimal places that are not 0?

Comment: Do you mean decimal *places*? A 'decimal' is a digit in base-10. Hard to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, decimal places, sorry but english is not my main language, and sometimes it's hard to express myself correctly.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question. 'Decimal' is much abused. Some people use it to mean the decimal *point,* others to mean the decimal 'places'. It doesn't mean either of those, and it certainly can't mean both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHAR_LENGTH()` and `LIKE` functions, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(column) > 4 
      AND column NOT LIKE "%0"
```